# cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'byte*'

Tags: c#, c++, arduino, rfid, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying converting arduino lib to universal windows platform but i'm stock on byte[] to byte* conversion.

For example:

```
public bool readCardSerial()
{
    byte status;
    byte[] str = new byte[MAX_LEN];

    status = anticoll(str);
    Array.Copy(serNum, str, 5);

    return (status == MI_OK);
}

public unsafe byte anticoll(byte* serNum)
{
    byte status;
    byte i;
    byte serNumCheck = 0;
    uint unLen;

    writeMFRC522(BitFramingReg, 0x00);

    serNum[0] = PICC_ANTICOLL;
    serNum[1] = 0x20;
    status = MFRC522ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, serNum, 2, serNum, &unLen);

    if (status == MI_OK)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            serNumCheck ^= serNum[i];
        if (serNumCheck != serNum[i])
            status = MI_ERR;
    }

    return status;
}
```

The str var on readCardSerial function is one of those errors.

I have my code on github if necessary - https://github.com/watashimeandeu/rfid.uwp

Thank you

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? `status = MFRC522ToCard();`? Are you sure that returns a `byte` and not a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links, they answer a similar question:

[How to assign byte[] as a pointer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693710/how-to-assign-byte-as-a-pointer-in-c-sharp)

[C# byte array to fixed int pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893815/c-sharp-byte-array-to-fixed-int-pointer)

You need something like, receive a `byte[]` in the method and then do the assignment

```
fixed(byte *packet = packetArray)
    {
        ... etc
    }
```